# MEF - How to compose a WCF RIA DomainService?

Tags: silverlight, mef, ria

Is it possible to use MEF to compose a WCF RIA Domain Service?

Let's say I've got below property in the Domain Service:

```
[Import(RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public TestClass Dependency{ get; set; }
```

And the TestClass..

```
[Export]
public class TestClass
{
    public void Do()
    {

    }
}
```

And I've got a DomainServiceFactory class:

```
public class DomainServiceFactory : IDomainServiceFactory
{
    private readonly ComposablePartCatalog _catalog;
    private readonly CompositionContainer _container;

    public DomainServiceFactory()
    {
        _catalog = new TypeCatalog(typeof(DomainService1), typeof(DomainService2));

        _container = new CompositionContainer(_catalog);
        //What should I call here? _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);
    }

    #region Implementation of IDomainServiceFactory

    public DomainService CreateDomainService(Type domainServiceType, DomainServiceContext context)
    {
        DomainService domainService;
        var export = _container.GetExports(domainServiceType, null, null).FirstOrDefault();
        if(export != null)
        {
            domainService = (DomainService) export.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            domainService = (DomainService)Activator.CreateInstance(domainServiceType);
        }


        domainService.Initialize(context);

        return domainService;

    }

    public void ReleaseDomainService(DomainService domainService)
    {
        domainService.Dispose();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Is SatisfyImportsOnce the method to build the container? The input parameter is a ComposablePart, what should I pass in?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You're already constructing your container when you call:

```
_container = new CompositionContainer(_catalog);
```

And as you haven't got any imports on your `DomainServiceFactory` there is little point calling `_container.SatisfyImportsOnce(this);`

When you call `export.Value`, it will automatically satisfy any imports on your domain service type. What are you missing/trying to achieve?

Comment: When calling GetExports(...) I'm getting null. That's why I thought it's not initialised.

Comment: Have you exported your types with a specific contract, I.e  [Export(typeof(DomainService))] or just [Export]?

Comment: Just [Export]. Will try [Export(typeof(DomainService))] on Monday. Hadn't realised.

Comment: Don't be too hasty, you may not need to. If your domain services have imports that can't be satisfied, MEF might have rejected those parts, have you ensured you have parts for any of your imports?

Comment: Looks like I can't use [Export(typeof(DomainService))] - The compiler throws an error when generating the client-side code for the DomainContext class because it tries to apply same the attribute, and DomainService is a server-only type.

Comment: BTW my domain services don't have any other dependencies besides that TestClass. And if I add [Export] to the DomainService, then I  get weird errors on the client-side. The client-side uses MEF too and it fails to resolve the shell if the DomainService classes have been decorated with [Export]. Does this ring any bell?

Comment: Seems to work when doing `domainService = (DomainService)Activator.CreateInstance(domainServiceType); _container.SatisfyImportsOnce(domainService);`